# Method Not Allowed (POST): /profiles/flash/ Method Not Allowed: /profiles/flash/

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

Well here I am simply trying to add follow toggle button in django template with django and jQuery ajax but I get an error

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /profiles/flash/
>
> Method Not Allowed: /profiles/flash/

I don't get it where i am making mistake. Even I triple checked my code.

html

```
<form method='post'>
          <button class="btn {% if is_following %}btn-warning{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %}" id="like-button" toggle="{{user.userprofile}}">{% csrf_token %}
           {% if is_following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}
          </button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

jquery,ajax

```
<script>
   var user = $('#test').attr('user');
   console.log(user,'test purpose');
  $(document).on('click', '#follow-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "profiles:follow" %}',
      data: {
        user_toggle: user,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("is_following").innerHTML = json['is_following']
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'profiles'

urlpatterns = [ path('<str:username>/',UserProfileDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
    path('follow/',follow,name = 'follow'),
]
```

views.py

```
def follow(request):
     if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        result = ''
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=request.user.username)
        is_following = False
        username_to_toggle=request.POST.get('user_toggle')
        follower = profile_.follower.filter(username__iexact=username_to_toggle).first()
        if follower:
            profile_.follower.remove(follower.id)
        else:
            new_follower = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username_to_toggle)
            profile_.follower.add(new_follower.id)
            is_following = True
        return JsonResponse({'is_following': is_following, })
```

If more information is required, then tell me in a comment section. I will update my question with that information.

Comment: So that message comes from your server, not allowing you to POST to that path. Try to use curl (or postman) to check your api first (as: without the ajax stuff) Additionally, what is the rest of your server? It seems that it is not exposing the endpoint in the way you think it is. You may want to add a MWE, so we can reproduce.

Comment: Well I am not using rest api for this. I am simply importing jsonresponse class from django/http file.

Comment: Okay, let me try to clarify, when the error occurs. You render some button, that works, right? Then you click that button, which sends a POST request to your python backend, right? And in the response you get a 405 right? MWE would help.

Comment: Yeah exactly that 405 response in console.

Comment: which means, your POST request works, but the server does not accept `POST` on `/profiles/flash/` Which is why we need to know, how you set up the server and the routes on your backend. If your `urls.py` is trying to mimic that, than I don't see any "post" there.  Where and how is that being used ? Also, that file does not mention `flash` anywhere? Is that some root url configured somewhere at the server?

Comment: Never mind I am actually new and learning full stack website developing. It maybe a small bug for you, and maybe it is but this is all new to me. So please explain your answer briefly if you figure out what's wrong here in my code.  :)

Comment: Well that flash is slug in url

Comment: Flash is actually username of user

Comment: okay, somewhere in your app you define the url patterns (I assume `urls.py` is being read somewhere. Can you give the context of where that is? I assume there is some keyword missing to tell it to accept POST (probably it defaults to GET). You may try that in Firefox (in the console: edit and resend Request; edit to 'GET' and see whether you get 405 again)

Comment: I have added views.py, where the follow function is linked with that url

Comment: Well in template you can see i am using a form. I just remove that from and defining a method post. what if i remove that and work with only button by adding onclick  function..

Comment: maybe that helps to annotate the follow method  `from rest_framework.decorators import api_view` and `@api_view(['POST'])` `def follow(request):` further info here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Comment: tell us if that works, then I can post that as an answer for others to find the solution quicker.

Comment: Alright. Just give me a mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `follow` method is missing the information, that it should accept `POST` requests. It defaults to `GET`.

In your `views.py` `import api_view` and annotate `follow` method:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view 

@api_view(['POST']) 
def follow(request):
    ...
```

More information here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

BTW: You don't need to have `action` property in `data` there. The fact, that you are sending the request via `POST` is hint enough.

Comment: I have asked new questions and That is on deployment, please have a look, I believe you  can fix that, Thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742988/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror-migration-accounts-0001-initi

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I update my previous code by the following code below:
html

```
          <button class="btn {% if is_following %}btn-warning{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %}" id="follow-button" toggle="{{user.userprofile}}">{% csrf_token %} #Change the id name
           {% if is_following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}
          </button>
        </div>
```

ajax :

```
<srcipt>
 $(document).on('click', '#follow-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "profiles:toggle" %}',
      data: {
        user_toggle: user,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'POST',
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("is_following").innerHTML = json['result']
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

views.py
#Change the function base view to class base view and add post function.

```
class UserProfileFollowToggle(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    def post(self, request):
            username_to_toggle = request.POST.get("user_toggle")
            profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, request.user.id ,username_to_toggle)
def toggle_follow(self, request_user,user_id, username_to_toggle):
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=request_user.username)
        is_following = False
        follower = profile_.follower.filter(username__iexact=username_to_toggle).first()
        if follower:
            profile_.follower.remove(follower.id)
        else:
            new_follower = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username_to_toggle)
            profile_.follower.add(new_follower.id)
            is_following = True
            return JsonResponse({'result': is_following, })
```